# Flatten lists of dicts on specified keys

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary

Goal: to read data from SQL table where a column contains JSON (arrays), extract certain keys/values from the JSON into new columns to then write to a new table. One of the joys of the original data format is that some data records are JSON arrays and some are not arrays (just JSON). Thus **we may start with**:

```
testcase = [(1, [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 11, 'b': 12, 'c': 13}]), 
            (2, {'a': 30, 'b': 40}), 
            (3, {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'd': 300})]
for x in testcase:
    print(x)
(1, [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 11, 'b': 12, 'c': 13}])
(2, {'a': 30, 'b': 40})
(3, {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'd': 300})
```

Note the first element of each tuple is the record id. The first record is an array of length two, the second and third records are not arrays. **The desired output is** (as a DataFrame):

```
    a   b   data
1   1   2   '{"c": 3}'
1   11  12  '{"c": 13}'
2   30  40  '{}'
3   100     200     '{"d": 300}'
```

Here you can see I've extracted keys 'a' and 'b' from the dicts into new columns, leaving the remaining keys/values in situ. The empty dict for id=2 is desirable behaviour.

First, I extracted the id and the data into separate lists. I take this opportunity to make the dict into a list of dicts (of length 1) so the types are now consistent:

```
id = [x[0] for x in testcase]
data_col = [x[1] if type(x[1]) == list else [x[1]] for x in testcase]
for x in data_col:
    print(x)
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 11, 'b': 12, 'c': 13}]
[{'a': 30, 'b': 40}]
[{'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'd': 300}]
```

It feels a bit of a clunky extra step to have to extract id and data_col as separate lists, although at least we have the nice property that we're not copying data:

```
id[0] is testcase[0][0]
True
data_col[0] is testcase[0][1]
True
```

And, as I say, I had to deal with the issue that some records contained arrays of dicts and some just dicts, so this makes them all consistent.

The main nitty gritty happens here, where I perform a dict comprehension in a double list comprehension to iterate over each dict:

```
popped = [(id, {key: element.pop(key, None) for key in ['a', 'b']}) \
for id, row in zip(id, data_col) for element in row]
for x in popped:
    print(x)
(1, {'a': 1, 'b': 2})
(1, {'a': 11, 'b': 12})
(2, {'a': 30, 'b': 40})
(3, {'a': 100, 'b': 200})
```

I need to be able to relate each new row with its original id, and the above achieves that, correctly reproducing the appropriate id value (1, 1, 2, 3). With a bit of housekeeping, I can then get all my target rows lined up:

```
import pandas as pd
from psycopg2.extras import Json
id2 = [x[0] for x in popped]
cols = [x[1] for x in popped]
data = [Json(item) for sublist in data_col for item in sublist]
popped_df = pd.DataFrame(cols, index=id2)
popped_df['data'] = data
```

And this gives me the desired DataFrame as shown above. But ... is all my messing about with lists necessary? I couldn't do a simple json_normalize because I don't want to extract all keys and it falls over with the combination of arrays and non-arrays.

It also needs to be as performant as possible as it's going to be processing multi-millions of rows. For this reason, I actually convert the DataFrame to a list using:
list(popped_df.itertuples())
to then pass to psycopg2.extras' execute_values()
so I may yet not bother constructing the DataFrame and just build the output list, but in this post I'm really asking if there's a cleaner, faster way to extract these specific keys from the dicts into new columns and rows, robust to whether the record is an array or not and keeping track of the associated record id.

I shied away from an end-to-end pandas approach, reading the data using pd.read_sql() as I was reading that DataFrame.to_sql() was relatively slow.

Comment: I am not quite sure that this would be relevant, but PostgreSQL can play nicely with json: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-json.html

Comment: Yeah, Postgres has nice JSON functions for sure. But as @jpp says, the data are messy. I want to be able to index easily on some fields currently inside the JSON. and sometimes the JSON is an array. Hence I'm wanting to do a bulk data engineering effort on millions of rows as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is messy, since the second element of your `testcase` can be either a `list` *or* a `dict`. In this case, you can construct a list via a `for` loop, then feed to the [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor:

```
testcase = [(1, [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 11, 'b': 12, 'c': 13}]), 
            (2, {'a': 30, 'b': 40}), 
            (3, {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'd': 300})]

L = []
for idx, data in testcase:
    for d in ([data] if isinstance(data, dict) else data):
        # string conversion not strictly necessary below
        others = str({k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in ('a', 'b')})
        L.append((idx, d['a'], d['b'], others))

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['index', 'a', 'b', 'data']).set_index('index')

print(df)

         a    b        data
index                      
1        1    2    {'c': 3}
1       11   12   {'c': 13}
2       30   40          {}
3      100  200  {'d': 300}
```

Comment: You use isinstance(data, dict). Is this more idiomatic than type(data) == dict?

Comment: @doctor, Yes, it is. Because it accounts for subclasses. For instance, `type(collections.defaultdict) == dict` returns `False`, while `collections.defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

testcase = [(1, [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 11, 'b': 12, 'c': 13}]),
            (2, {'a': 30, 'b': 40}),
            (3, {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'd': 300})]


def split_dict(d, keys=['a', 'b']):
    """Split the dictionary by keys"""
    preserved = {key: value for key, value in d.items() if key in keys}
    complement = {key: value for key, value in d.items() if key not in keys}
    return preserved, complement


def get_row(val):
    preserved, complement = split_dict(val)
    preserved['data'] = complement
    return preserved


rows = []
index = []
for i, values in testcase:
    if isinstance(values, list):
        for value in values:
            rows.append(get_row(value))
            index.append(i)
    else:
        rows.append(get_row(values))
        index.append(i)


df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, index=index)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
     a    b        data
1    1    2    {'c': 3}
1   11   12   {'c': 13}
2   30   40          {}
3  100  200  {'d': 300}
```